# How to Trigger comment_form_after action if comment_form() not used

Tags: comments, actions

A plugin I want to use has a filter like so:

> add_action('comment_form_after','yoast_track_comment_form');

The theme I'm using doesn't use the comment_form() call and I believe that this means the filter isn't being called. The yoast_track_comment_form just adds some jquery tracking, so what is the best way to trigger it.

Should I just call it directly from within the plugin code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply place the hook yourself in your theme (or better: Child theme) template:

```
do_action( 'comment_form_after' );
```

Comment: This worked.  Thank you for showing me how to trigger these events.

Comment: @Adam Could you please mark it as solved?